# How to change the color of a graph to rainbow gradient

Tags: plotting, color

```
f[x_, y_] := 1/5 y^2 (1/2 + .8 y) - (1/2 x^2 - 1/10)^2
Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-3, 5}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 2, 2}, ClippingStyle -> None]
```

This is the code for the first orange color graph that I am trying to get to look like the second rainbow color graph. I know how to change the color of it but I am unsure how to change it to the rainbow pattern. If you know how to change the shape to be closer to the rainbow graph it would be very appreciated but I don't mind doing that part on my own. Thank-you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Look up the `ColorFunction` option.

Answer (score 3):

You need to look not only `ColorFunction` but you should understand the option `ColorFunctionScaling->False`. Anyway, a version close to your second image could be created with

```
f[x_, y_] := 1/5 y^2 (1/2 + .8 y) - (1/2 x^2 - 1/10)^2

Plot3D[f[x, y], {x, -2, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, PlotRange -> {-3, 5}, 
 BoxRatios -> {1, 2, 2}, ClippingStyle -> None, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[-z - 1/4]], Mesh -> 50]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]